# Regular Expression for sql exception to find constraint name

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find out the constraint name of sql exceptions in java for foreign key or unique key.

The exception message may be as:

ORA-02292: integrity constraint (BB08.FK1_STUDENT_UNDER_REGISTRATION) violated

ORA-00001: unique constraint (BAO4_OWN.PK2_JBPM_LOG) violated

ORA-00001: unique constraint (CRUCIBLE.PK_C0054150) violated

I need to get the regular expression that can find complete string that matches FK/PK2/PK like FK1_STUDENT_UNDER_REGISTRATION, PK2_JBPM_LOG, PK_C0054150 here respectively. There is no length limit for constrain names.

Using [regexr](https://regexr.com/) I tried to find a regular expression as `(\FK|fk)\w*` but that was not working and not compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following regex pattern:

```
\bconstraint \(([^)]+)\)
```

Sample script:

```js
var input = "ORA-02292: integrity constraint (BB08.FK1_STUDENT_UNDER_REGISTRATION) violated\nORA-00001: unique constraint (BAO4_OWN.PK2_JBPM_LOG) violated\nORA-00001: unique constraint (CRUCIBLE.PK_C0054150) violated";
var regexp = /\bconstraint \(([^)]+)\)/ig;
match = regexp.exec(input);
while (match != null) {
    console.log(match[1])
    match = regexp.exec(input);
}
```

By the way, if you are using a more recent version of JavaScript which supports `matchAll()`, then a much easier approach would be:

```
var input = "ORA-02292: integrity constraint (BB08.FK1_STUDENT_UNDER_REGISTRATION) violated\nORA-00001: unique constraint (BAO4_OWN.PK2_JBPM_LOG) violated\nORA-00001: unique constraint (CRUCIBLE.PK_C0054150) violated";
var matches = input.matchAll(/\bconstraint \(([^)]+)\)/ig);
```

And then just access the first capture group for the constraint names.